# Get the sum of a column in SQL - column is not directly from a table but has been calc'd

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm building a table in SQL and have a column called 'DMA_FEE' which is the result of multiplying 2 other columns I brought in from existing tables. Any syntax I see about summing all the value in a column all have a 'from table' piece to them e.g.
SELECT
SUM( column_name )
FROM
table;

Considering I have calc'd this column in question, it doesn't come from a table so I can not use this syntax and can't see any other solutions. Here is my code for columns so far and the last one is where I get my DMA_FEE calc.

```
SELECT A.*,
A.TRANSACTION_ID,
B.AMOUNT,
B.CHARGE_ID,
C.CHARGE_TYPE_ID,
D.CHARGE_GROUP,
E.ACCOUNT_NAME,
F.SIG_ENTITY_LABEL,
E.TRADING_USERID,
E.EXCHANGE_ID,
E.TRADEABLE_INSTR_NAME,
G.INSTR_SUBTYPE_LABEL,
G.UNDERLYING_SYM_BLOOMBERG,
G.FUT_EXPIRATION_DATE,
E.TRADE_DATE,
timestamp_table.timeformated,
A.RATE * A.BASIS_VALUE DMA_FEE
FROM REPLDOADM.IRE_ESTIMATE_TRANS_MAP A
LEFT JOIN REPLDOADM.IRE_CHARGES_ESTIMATE B ON A.ESTIMATE_ID = B.ESTIMATE_ID
LEFT JOIN REPLDOADM.IRE_CHARGES_LU C ON B.CHARGE_ID = C.CHARGE_ID
LEFT JOIN REPLDOADM.ire_charge_types_lU D ON C.CHARGE_TYPE_ID = D.CHARGE_TYPE_ID
LEFT JOIN REPLDOADM.VW_IRE_TRADE_TRANSACTIONS E ON A.TRANSACTION_ID = E.TRANS_ID
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT to_char(create_ts, 'HH24:MI:SS') as timeformated, TRANS_ID
FROM REPLDOADM.VW_IRE_TRADE_TRANSACTIONS) timestamp_table ON (A.TRANSACTION_ID = 
timestamp_table.TRANS_ID)
LEFT JOIN REPLDOADM.VW_IRE_ACCOUNTS F ON E.ACCOUNT_NAME = F.PB_ACCOUNT_NAME
LEFT JOIN stig_adm.INSTRUMENT_UNIVERSE G ON E.TRADEABLE_INSTR_NAME = G.SHORT_NAME
WHERE timeformated >= '07:00:00' AND timeformated <= '18:00:00'
AND FUT_EXPIRATION_DATE >= add_months( trunc(sysdate), -12)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Before we get too far... You show you are selecting `A.*` and then immediately after that, you are also selecting `A.TRANSACTION_ID`. What's the point of that? Do you understand what the `*` means in `A.*`? This is a much more basic issue than your question (which I haven't even read yet, to be hones).

Comment: Also - I removed the `sqldeveloper` tag, since your question has nothing to do with your client application; it's purely an Oracle SQL question.

Comment: You should prefer to use `AS` to create aliases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the sum of all DMA_FEE values repeated alongside the other columns, add `SUM(A.RATE * A.BASIS_VALUE) OVER () as DMA_FEE_TOTAL` to your SELECT clause. This is an *analytical* or *window function* version of SUM().

If you just want to calculate the total separately, you can wrap your entire query in parentheses and treat it as a table (this is called an *inline view*):

```
select SUM(DMA_FEE)
from (YOUR ENTIRE QUERY);
```

If you want something else, please edit your question to add an example of your desired output results.

--Edit--

Yes, it's common to *group by* a set of columns.

For window functions, it goes in the `partition by` clause:

```
SUM(A.RATE * A.BASIS_VALUE) OVER (partition by TRADEABLE_INSTR_NAME, TRADING_USERID, UNDERLYING_SYM_BLOOMBERG) as DMA_FEE_TOTAL
```

For aggregate functions, it goes in a `group by` clause. Note that when you have a `group by` clause, all of your SELECTed columns need to be either (a) group by columns, or (b) aggregate functions like SUM()

```
select TRADEABLE_INSTR_NAME, 
  TRADING_USERID, 
  UNDERLYING_SYM_BLOOMBERG, 
  SUM(DMA_FEE) as DMA_FEE_SUBTOTAL
from (YOUR ENTIRE QUERY)
group by TRADEABLE_INSTR_NAME, TRADING_USERID, UNDERLYING_SYM_BLOOMBERG;
```

Comment: *this is called an inline view* - i've always called them subqueries

Comment: @CaiusJard also accurate! an inline view is [a type of subquery](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Using-Subqueries.html#GUID-53A705B6-0358-4E2B-92ED-A83DE83DFD20).

Comment: @kfinity Both solutions worked, thanks. I have ticked the answer as it is perfect however another related Q -  Is there a way to sum this DMA_FEE column based on other columns matching? Sort of the way an excel pivot table would work? For example I would want to sum the fee based on rows having the same TRADEABLE_INSTR_NAME, TRADING_USERID and UNDERLYING_SYM_BLOOMBERG. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sounds like you want `SUM(A.RATE * A.BASIS_VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY TRADEABLE_INSTR_NAME, TRADING_USERID, UNDERLYING_SYM_BLOOMBERG) as DMA_FEE_TOTAL` - summing will be like "subttotals in groups where rows all have identical values in TRADEABLE_INSTR_NAME, TRADING_USERID and UNDERLYING_SYM_BLOOMBERG"

Comment: works perfectly and logic is very clears for going forward - tks